# Controlar mediante jquery si se produce un overflow-x mediante condicionales

Tags: javascript, jquery

He estado buscando y no sé si es que busco mal o no hay mucho información. Me gustaría saber si se puede controlar cuando se produce un overflow en el eje X desde javascript/jquery.

Básicamente lo que me pasa es que tengo una serie de tablas que dependiendo de los datos, esta se puede desbordar en el eje X y cuando sucede esto quiero cambiar el comportamiento de esta mediante una variable booleana.

Mi pregunta es, se puede aplicar un condicional `if else` que controle el overflow? Algo así,

```
if (overflow-x == True){
    var variable == True;
}else{
    var variable == False;
}
```

Se que no pongo código mio, pero es que no sé como se hace, ni realmente sis e puede (imagino que si).

¡Un saludo y muchas gracias!

Comment: Podrías tomar el tamaño de la ventana, y el width del elemento y con una resta saber sí excede del eje X

Answer (score 0):

también podrías hacerlo con una regla css simple, para que se adapte automaticamente la tabla, aunque no sea exactamente lo que buscas pero es una alternativa:

Creas una clase CSS con overflow-x que hará que se ponga la barra si la tabla es muy grande y le puedes dar scroll lateral, solo se pondrá el scroll si la tabla es muy grande.

```
.table-responsive {
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Ejemplo, aplicado en HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .w {
            padding: 1rem;
            width: 200px;
            background-color: blue;
        }

        .table-responsive {
            overflow-x: auto;
        }
    </style>

<body>
    <div class="w">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>campo</th>
                        <th>campo</th>
                        <th>campo</th>
                        <th>campo</th>
                        <th>campo</th>
                        <th>campo</th>
                        <th>campo</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>dato</td>
                        <td>dato</td>
                        <td>dato</td>
                        <td>dato</td>
                        <td>dato</td>
                        <td>dato</td>
                        <td>dato</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Con la clase css aplicada:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin la clase aplicada:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias pero necesito hacerlo por JS porque no es simplemente que se desborde la tabla. Y por ello necesito controlarlo con condicionales. ¡Gracias igualmente!